# SSIS package cannot pull from one SharePoint list, all others are okay. Where do I start?

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, odata

I have SSIS packages that use the oData source to pull from SharePoint lists and libraries.  Most of them work.  One of them does not.  The connection tests fine, but when I go to edit the data source and specify the list I want, trying to retrieve the columns gives me an error that says "An error occurred while retrieving the metadata".

There's *one* computed field in this list, and when I had the SharePoint Dev remove it in the development environment, the package worked.  Is there any way I can configure the oData source to automatically skip this field?  I may not be allowed to have it removed in production.

Answer (score 0):

That computed field was already deprecated, and has been removed.  It works now.